# how convert array to each array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, assign

Actually, I'm not sure if my title is correct.

If I have a data below like that,

```
const data = [
 fruit: ['apple','banana', 'peer'],
 vegetable: ['tomato','onion', 'leek']
]
```

How can I convert below that?

```
const filteredData = [
 {fruit: 'apple', vegetable: 'tomato'},
 {fruit: 'banana', vegetable: 'onion'},
 {fruit: 'peer', vegetable: 'leek'},
]
```

Comment: are you sure your `data` is an array

Comment: The first one isn't valid syntax. Arrays don't have keys like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array of objects from multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539591/how-to-create-an-array-of-objects-from-multiple-arrays)

Comment: second [near identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71181200/how-to-combine-two-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects) question in a day, is there a new tutorial up somewhere?

Comment: @Ivar actually they can as arrays are just objects, but they can't be initialized that way,  and it's not advised. (`const data = []; data.fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'peer']; console.log(data.fruit);`)

Comment: @pilchard I tried to cover myself by adding "like that" (as the main point being that you can't define keys in array _literals_). I could've been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an object in that case. You can get the expected result using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = { fruit: ['apple','banana', 'peer'], vegetable: ['tomato','onion', 'leek'] };

const arr = data.fruit.map((fruit, i) => ({ fruit, vegetable: data.vegetable[i] }));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is this:

```
const data = {
    fruit: ['apple','banana', 'peer'],
    vegetable: ['tomato','onion', 'leek']
}
```

```
const filteredData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.fruit.length; i++) {
    filteredData.push({ fruit: data.fruit[i], vegetable: data.vegetable[i]} );
};
```