# how can I map given javascript array to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

Can someone please help me resolve below object in javascript? I would be so grateful for your help.

```
//Current Object:
Data: {
    Name: [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’],
    Id: [1, 2, 3, 4]
      }
```

```
//Expected output: 

Data: {
      {Name: ‘A’, Id: 1},
      {Name: ‘B’, Id: 2},
      {Name: ‘C’, Id: 3},
      {Name: ‘D’, Id: 4}
    }
```

I have tried mapping it with Object.keys() and map() function, but it didn't help much. I am a beginner at Javascript, looking for someone's help.

Comment: _"I have tried mapping it..."_ We'd love to see those attempts! Also, you should start by NOT using curly quotes in code. And after you replace those curly single quotes, you should make a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. What errors are you seeing when you try?

Comment: is that invalid output what you expect? or you meant an array of objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine the values of two arrays into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448966/combine-the-values-of-two-arrays-into-object)

Comment: and [Combining two arrays to form a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256257/combining-two-arrays-to-form-a-javascript-object) or [How to combine two arrays into an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71181200/how-to-combine-two-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects) or [How to create an array of objects from multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539591/how-to-create-an-array-of-objects-from-multiple-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an object:

```js
const Data = {
  { Name: 'A', Id: 1 },
  { Name: 'B', Id: 2 },
  { Name: 'C', Id: 3 },
  { Name: 'D', Id: 4 }
};
```

But instead of that you can make an array:

```js
const Data = [
  { Name: 'A', Id: 1 },
  { Name: 'B', Id: 2 },
  { Name: 'C', Id: 3 },
  { Name: 'D', Id: 4 }
];
```

Example code:

```js
const data = {
  name: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  id: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

const mappedData = data.name.map((element, index) => ({
  name: data.name[index],
  id: data.id[index]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper function with destructuring arguments and `.map()` like this:

```js
const obj = {
  Data: {
    Name: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    Id: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
};


const obj2ArrOfObj = ({ Name, Id }) => Name.map((name, idx) => ({ Name: name, Id: Id[idx] }));

const mappedObj = {
  Data: obj2ArrOfObj(obj.Data)
};

console.log(mappedObj);
```